# How to set text on status bar and enabled close button in QDockWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdockwidget, qstatusbar

I have a QDockWidget and QToolBar in it. I tried to set `StatusBar` for QdockWidget but it could not be set.
Every QDockWidget has default close button (top most right corner) but my DockWidget does not have it ?
Why ? And how to bring it back ?

```
myClass::myClass(QWidget* parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent)

{
   hide();
   QWidget* newWidget = new QWidget();
   QBoxLayout* tLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom,newWidget );
   tLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

   QLabel *label = new QLabel("My Window",this);

   this->setTitleBarWidget(label);
   tbar = new QToolBar;
   tbar->setIconSize(QSize(35,35));
   tbar->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
   tLayout->addWidget(tbar,0,Qt::AlignTop);
   QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
   QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
   view->setScene(scene);
   tLayout->addWidget(view);
   newWidget ->setLayout(tLayout);

   bar = new QStatusBar();
   bar->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
   this->setWidget(bar);

   setWidget(newWidget);
}
```

How to set status bar ? and enable close button ?

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// change to:
QWidget* newWidget = new QWidget(this);
...
tbar = new QToolBar(this);
...
bar = new QStatusBar(this);

// replace:
this->setWidget(bar);
// with:
tLayout->addWidget(bar);

// replace:
this->setTitleBarWidget(label);
// with:
titleBarWidget()->layout()->insertItem(0, label);
```

Comment: It worked for Status bar perfectly.  Can you show me , how to enable default close button ( right side top most)  ?